# error in installing GEOquery package in R

Tags: r, installation, package

I am trying to install GEOquery packages but I get an error message.
Configuration: Rstudio (2022.02.0 Build 443 "Prairie Trillium" Release (9f796939, 2022-02-16) for Windows)
Code that I used to install the packages

```
if (!requireNamespace("BiocManager", quietly = TRUE))
  
  install.packages("BiocManager")

BiocManager::install("GEOquery")
```

Error message:

```
'getOption("repos")' replaces Bioconductor standard repositories, see
'?repositories' for details

replacement repositories:
    CRAN: https://cran.rstudio.com/

Bioconductor version 3.10 (BiocManager 1.30.16), R 3.6.3 (2020-02-29)
Installing package(s) 'BiocVersion', 'GEOquery'
also installing the dependencies ‘Biobase’, ‘limma’

trying URL 'https://bioconductor.org/packages/3.10/bioc/bin/windows/contrib/3.6/Biobase_2.46.0.zip'
Content type 'application/zip' length 2421436 bytes (2.3 MB)
downloaded 2.3 MB

trying URL 'https://bioconductor.org/packages/3.10/bioc/bin/windows/contrib/3.6/limma_3.42.2.zip'
Content type 'application/zip' length 3096814 bytes (3.0 MB)
downloaded 3.0 MB

trying URL 'https://bioconductor.org/packages/3.10/bioc/bin/windows/contrib/3.6/BiocVersion_3.10.1.zip'
Content type 'application/zip' length 8903 bytes
downloaded 8903 bytes

trying URL 'https://bioconductor.org/packages/3.10/bioc/bin/windows/contrib/3.6/GEOquery_2.54.1.zip'
Content type 'application/zip' length 13850910 bytes (13.2 MB)
downloaded 13.2 MB

Error in unzip(zipname, exdir = dest) : 
  cannot open file 'C:/Users/Myname/Documents/R/win-library/3.6/file54c75107e2c/Biobase/doc/BiobaseDevelopment.pdf':  Permission denied
```

I already tried to restart R as administrator but it does not work

Thank you

Comment: Does `Myname` in the file path have spaces or accented characters? Try creating a directory in a file path without such characters and using this as the value of the argument `destdir=`, starting with the simplest situation that still causes problems e.g., `BiocManager::install("Biobase", destdir = "C:/...")`

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But it does not have any spaces or accented characters...